# Distance between two point along the cylinder surface

Tags: matlab, geometry

How to find out distance between point along the surface from one point to all other point on the cylinder surface.

XYZ coordinates of points are known

e.g

suppose 4 points are there on the surface of the cylinder here i want to find out following data i.e distance between point(1-2),point(1-3),point(1-4),point(2-3),point(2-4),point(3,4) along the surface.H

Comment: There's no way we can answer this question with the information currently given. What's the size of the cylinder? What's its orientation? What's it's radius?

Comment: Radius is "45"mm and height is "70"mm. Orientation: base resting on XY plane and having base circle origin (0,0,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the geodesic of a cylinder. Since you mentioned Matlab in the tag, you can use [this tool](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6522-geodesic)

Comment: Thank you sir for providing solution for problem.......yes its exact what i am looking for.....

Comment: If I helped you, please click the ✓ to accept the answer. And you welcome.